# How to use multiple objects and their methods from multiple classes

Tags: java

I have three classes. I want to use all classes in one function from another classes. I need to collect all `Letter` class objects and put the result from `getName` and `getWeight` from each object in a HashMap. I need to this with `Package` and `Deliverer` as well.

Already tried to use `getDeclaredField/getDeclaredClasses`.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Parcel
{
    protected static void addWeight()
    {
        Class<?>[] classes = Letter.class.getDeclaredClasses();
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println("Class = " + classes[i].getName());
        }

        Field[] allFieldsLetter = Letter.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < allFieldsLetter.length; i++) {
            double value = Letter.getWeight();
            Delivery.weightList.put(Letter.getName(), value);
        }
        Field[] allFieldsPackage = Package.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < allFieldsPackage.length; i++) {
            double value = Package.getWeight();
            Delivery.weightList.put(Package.getName(), value);
        }
        Field[] allFieldsDeliverer = Deliverer.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < allFieldsDeliverer.length; i++) {
            double value = Deliverer.getWeight() * 5;
            Delivery.deliverer.put(Deliverer.getName(), value);
        }
    }
}
```

If I create 3 `Deliverer` objects for example, I want to get 3 three names, one for each object, and their weights in a HashMap `(Delivery.deliverer.put(Deliverer.getName(), value);)`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense, you are using `for` loops but you are not accessing values from any array or any other type of collection inside them and you talk about having 3 objects of a type but all your code uses static methods and variables. Is the hashmap supposed to be a static instance for each class or a member variable or perhaps a global collection for all object types?

Comment: I don't think you mean to be using the reflective classes/methods for class and fields.  Your comments suggest you mean to be doing something much more normal like creating list of objects and then looping over them.  I'm I on the right track?

Comment: Your on the right track fedup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example where Delivery has a constructor that accepts the name and the value of weight as a parameter.

```
List<Delivery> myDeliveryInstances = new ArrayList<Delivery>();

myDeliveryInstances.add(new Delivery("D1", 10));
myDeliveryInstances.add(new Delivery("D2", 25));
myDeliveryInstances.add(new Delivery("D3", 50));

Map<String, Long) deliverer = new HashMap<String, Long>();
for (Delivery delivery : myDeliveryInstances) {
    deliverer.put(delivery.getName(), delivery.getWeight());
}
```

Comment: When I get home will try this solution, seems to be a pretty good one ;)